# vite can't recognize tailwind classes in laravel application

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css, vite

I have laravel application I use tailwind in it. But when I write a tailwind class, say, `w-100` it returns :

> [vite:css] [postcss] C:\Users\eymen\OneDrive\Desktop\work\websites\elnaj7\resources\css\app.css:4:1: The `w-100` class does not exist. If `w-100` is a custom class, make sure it is defined within a `@layer` directive.
> file: C:\Users\eymen\OneDrive\Desktop\work\websites\elnaj7\resources\css\app.css:4:1
> error during build:
> CssSyntaxError: [postcss] C:\Users\eymen\OneDrive\Desktop\work\websites\elnaj7\resources\css\app.css:4:1: The `w-100` class does not exist. If `w-100` is a custom class, make sure it is defined within a `@layer` directive.
> at Input.error (C:\Users\eymen\OneDrive\Desktop\work\websites\elnaj7\node_modules\postcss\lib\input.js:148:16)
> at AtRule.error (C:\Users\eymen\OneDrive\Desktop\work\websites\elnaj7\node_modules\postcss\lib\node.js:60:32)
> at processApply (C:\Users\eymen\OneDrive\Desktop\work\websites\elnaj7\node_modules\tailwindcss\lib\lib\expandApplyAtRules.js:357:29)
> at C:\Users\eymen\OneDrive\Desktop\work\websites\elnaj7\node_modules\tailwindcss\lib\lib\expandApplyAtRules.js:505:9
> at C:\Users\eymen\OneDrive\Desktop\work\websites\elnaj7\node_modules\tailwindcss\lib\processTailwindFeatures.js:55:50
> at plugins (C:\Users\eymen\OneDrive\Desktop\work\websites\elnaj7\node_modules\tailwindcss\lib\index.js:38:63)
> at LazyResult.runOnRoot (C:\Users\eymen\OneDrive\Desktop\work\websites\elnaj7\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:339:16)
> at LazyResult.runAsync (C:\Users\eymen\OneDrive\Desktop\work\websites\elnaj7\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:393:26)
> at async compileCSS (file:///C:/Users/eymen/OneDrive/Desktop/work/websites/elnaj7/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-4da11a5e.js:44551:25)
> at async Object.transform (file:///C:/Users/eymen/OneDrive/Desktop/work/websites/elnaj7/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-4da11a5e.js:44055:55)

I use two input files, app and user.

layout (shortened):

```
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    @vite(['resources/css/app.css'])

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}"> <!--when I remove this line all tailwind basic stylings get removed-->
    <!-- styles -->
    @yield('styles')
    <!-- Head Scripts -->
    @yield('head-scripts')
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        @yield('content')
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

vite.config:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/css/user.css',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

tailwind.config

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './resources/views/auth/**/*.blade.php',
    './resources/views/errors/**/*.blade.php',
    './resources/views/layouts/**/*.blade.php',
    './resources/views/user/**/*.blade.php',
    './storage/framework/views/*.php',
  ],
  theme: {
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

the output file has some generated classes because I tried to run tailwind without vite. But lots of problems happened and I returned to vite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`w-100` isn't a default Tailwind class, the biggest you have is `w-96`. That's why it's telling you to add it to the config as a custom class.

Here's Tailwind's docs on widths: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/width